# Tikzscale, trim axis left/right, and externalizing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external, tikzscale

`tikzscale` and `trim axis` do not play well together, with the produced figure being larger than requested because it ignores the size of the labels.

I was wondering whether it is possible to use both `tikzscale` to get exact sizing of the figure and the `trim axis left` and `trim axis right` parameters in the `tikzpicture` environment so that the figure captions are centered with respect to the axis rather than the axis+labels. It'd be great to retain the ability to do this even when the figures are externalized, if possible.

Here is what currently happens:

[image]

And here's a MWE:

## Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,tikzscale}

\begin{document}
  This is just some random text that will span over two lines. This is just some random text that will span over two lines.
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[%
      xlabel={x},
      ylabel={y},
      width=\textwidth,
      height=0.25\textwidth]
    \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{No tikzscale and trim axis left/right}
  \end{figure}

  This is just some random text that will span over two lines. This is just some random text that will span over two lines.
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,axisratio=4]{no-trim.tikz}
    \caption{tikzscale only}
  \end{figure}

  This is just some random text that will span over two lines. This is just some random text that will span over two lines.
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,axisratio=4]{trim.tikz}
    \caption{tikzscale and trim axis left/right}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## no-trim.tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
  xlabel={x},
  ylabel={y},]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

## trim.tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[%
  xlabel={x},
  ylabel={y},]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

## Edit:

Jake suggested that the question would be better phrased as how to move the captions so that they are aligned to the axis of the figure rather than the opposite. So, assuming that the typical scenario is the one in Figure 2, what would I have to change to center the caption with respect to the axis? Again, I'll be producing tens of figures like this so an automated solution is what I'm aiming for (that's why I assumed that the way to go was with `trim axis left` and `trim axis right`).

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to be able to specify an overall width for the axes, say, 10cm, including the labels, and you want the axes to be centered with regard to the axis box. If you have one axis with very large labels, the axis box should shrink so that the overall width is still 10cm. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I want the width of the figure to be exact like in Figure 2, but I also want the figure caption to be centered only with respect to the axis like in Figure 3. But I'd prefer to have this done automagically and not lose the ability to externalize if possible.

Comment: I'd like to try it before I contact the maintainer. I've added the line you told me to `tikzscale.sty` and I am seeing no difference. Is there anything else I need to do before the changes are applied?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Jake. I did that and I see something weird. The width is obviously right; the alignment of the caption is right; but the figure is not at the right place --- it's outside the `\textwidth` margin. This is what happens: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kc22v0abk63x7p1/almost-there.png

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want the resulting figure to look exactly like Figure 2, but with the caption centered along the axis. I guess that is equivalent to moving the caption to the right.

Comment: Okay, that will require a very different approach, and is really independent of whether you use `tikzscale` or not. The caption is always centered with regard to the text area on the page, it doesn't care about the content of the `figure` float. Personally, I think it would look pretty weird if the captions weren't centered on the page, though. Maybe you can edit your question to make it clearer that you want to adjust the positions of the captions, and not of the plots?

Comment: I just appended an "Edit" part to my question, Jake. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @sudosensei, I bumped into this question thanks to its title. Strangely I see that there's no focus on the `external`ization-related problem. If I add the two lines `\usetikzlibrary{external}`, `\tikzexternalize` to the code I obtain a code which typeset the third picture over and over again, never considering it up-to-date. (I would prefer not posting a new question, since I should simply copy and paste this one.) Did you solve this aspect of the problem in some way?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I wouldn't know unfortunately. Sounds like a different issue. Feel free to use my MWE. That being said, the first thing you should check is whether the `trim axis` options are actually causing the issue; otherwise, you'd need to edit the MWE to better suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: steal the coordinatess of axes from the Ti*k*Z picture.

Step 2: apply an offset to the caption

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\pgf@xd

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[h!]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[name=my plot,xlabel={x},ylabel={y},
                         width=\textwidth,height=0.25\textwidth]
                \addplot{x};
            \end{axis}
            \tikz@parse@node(my plot.south)       \pgf@xd=\pgf@x
            \tikz@parse@node(my plot.outer south) \global\advance\pgf@xd by-\pgf@x
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Some caption. .noitpac emoS :1 erugiF\kern-2\pgf@xd}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]