# Combining tikzexternalize with tikzscale and trim axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikzscale

Attempting to build the following results in pdflatex hanging and building the file over and over again forever:

```
% !TEX options=--shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% \tikzexternalize  % !!! B
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{tex-stackexchange.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[trim axis left, trim axis right]  % !!! A
\begin{axis}[
  width=\textwidth,
  height=0.25\textwidth,
  xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5]
\addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4.5,4) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tex-stackexchange.tikz}
\end{figure}

This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.

\end{document}
```

Commenting out the line marked `!!! A` makes everything render correctly, but without externalization:

[image: expected]

Commenting out the line marked `!!! B` makes the externalization appear to work, but the plot is now the wrong width.

Commenting out neither results in pdflatex hanging.

---

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125146/41112) may seem related, but it:

- Is asking for behavior that is obtained by *not* using `trim axis`
- Did not get an answer about `externalize`, which was in the title

Answer (score 1):

According to what I find you only need to use the `mode=list and make` option. Of course, you also need to execute the make file, the prompt will tell you what to do on your machine (hopefully;-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]  % !!! B
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{tex-stackexchange.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[trim axis left, trim axis right]  % !!! A
\begin{axis}[
  width=\textwidth,
  height=0.25\textwidth,
  xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5]
\addplot coordinates { (1,1) (2,3) (3,2) (4.5,4) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tex-stackexchange.tikz}
\end{figure}

This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.
This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text. This is a lot of text.

\end{document}
```

[image]